# How to transfer data from java module to flutter when using FlutterActivity?

Tags: android, flutter

When encapsulating a module on flutter in an existing application in java and using FlutterActivity, I had the problem of passing of string.
If using variant:

```
Button mInvokeFlutterActivity = findViewById(R.id.invoke_flutter_activity);
mInvokeFlutterActivity.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(
        FlutterActivity.withNewEngine().initialRoute(link).build(context)
                .putExtra("background_mode", "opaque")
                .putExtra("destroy_engine_with_activity", true)
));
```

then in main.dart, can catch the link variable as window.defaultRouteName. But if use another intent:

```
 Button mInvokeFlutterActivity = findViewById(R.id.invoke_flutter_activity);
 mInvokeFlutterActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         startActivity(FlutterActivity.withCachedEngine("my_engine_id").build(context)           
        );
    }
});
```

then using window.defaultRouteName will become impossible. Can anyone tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

"The concept of an initial route is available when configuring a FlutterActivity or a FlutterFragment with a new FlutterEngine. However, FlutterActivity and FlutterFragment don’t offer the concept of an initial route when using a cached engine. This is because a cached engine is expected to already be running Dart code, which means it’s too late to configure the initial route."

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-screen

Answer (score 0):

Use invoke method to get data from Java or Kotlin, read [this article](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to understand how to use it.